# Nginx as a forward proxy for websockets and post requests

Tags: nginx, post, websocket

I'm currently using nginx as a forward proxy for websockets, and it has been working fine up to now. Client connects with:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://10.30.0.142:8020/');
```

I want to forward a post request as well. In this case, client adds /post to the ws address, so that the address is extended to 'ws://10.30.0.142:8020/post'. However requests to that address return:

```
http://10.30.0.142/post 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm using the following configuration file (nginx.conf), which most probably is wrong for the post request (location /post/):

```
upstream websocket {
        server 127.0.0.1:8010;
}

server {
        listen       8020;
        server_name  server;
        root /var/www/html;
        expires off;

        keepalive_timeout 0;

        access_log /dev/null;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://websocket;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }

        location /post/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8010;
       }

        location ~* \.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ { }

    }

 }
```

How should I configure this file correctly to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily, the fix is super simple: Just change the line `location /post/ {` to `location /post {`, the extra slash matches only request to `/post/<something else>` which, based on your description, isn't what you want.

In fact, you may even want to change that line to `location =/post {` if you want to match only requests to `/post`, not requests to `/post<some other string>` or `/post/<some other string>` as well.